# Renormalization of worldsheet energy-momentum tensor

Tags: string-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

At the end of section 2.3, Polchinski (in his volume 1) derives the energy-momentum tensor for free massless scalars on worldsheet. He adds a footnote that "the only possible ambiguity introduced by the renormalization is a constant times $\delta_{ab}$, from the subtraction".

What does he mean?

How does it relate to the familiar renormalization in field theory?

Answer (score 2):

Polchinski probably means that the regularized stress-energy tensor is the classical tensor plus some constant terms proportional to $\delta_{ab}$. Hence, this regularized stress tensor is also conserved.